# Any way to migrate a legacy "tokenlist" token to use Metaplex Fungible Token Metadata if the token's mint authority is disabled?

Tags: spl-token, metaplex, token, authority, token-list

Title says it all. We have a token with "Current mint authority: disabled". We would love to add Metadata and update the logo but it appears this may be impossible now that the old tokenlist.json file method is EOL.

Comment: Alternatively.... are there any kind developers with access to the old archived token-list repository that could help me update a logo image file saved there?

Answer (score 1):

The answer, unfortunately, is "no". The Metaplex Token Metadata program requires a signature from the mint authority.